# Could not find a version that satisfies conda for python 3

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, command, installation, conda

I want to install conda command not anaconda but I have this erreur all time :

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install conda
Collecting conda
  Using cached conda-4.3.13.tar.gz
Collecting pycosat>=0.6.1 (from conda)
  Using cached pycosat-0.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting requests>=2.12.4 (from conda)
  Using cached requests-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ruamel.yaml>=0.11.14 (from conda)
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.14.5.tar.gz
Collecting menuinst (from conda)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda)
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for menuinst (from conda)

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Please don't use pip to install and setup conda. Please download the official conda installer available at https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows

Comment: If you prefer to use Miniconda, then visit: https://conda.io/miniconda.html

Comment: thank you for your I help but ask about conda command not anaconda or miniconda thanks again

Comment: They both provide conda. Miniconda provides conda and the minimal set of packages required to run conda and Anaconda provides conda and a plethora of other packages for data analytics.

Comment: miniconda does not provide debug symbols and binaries like official python.org installer

Answer (score 15):

You can install conda 4.2.7 using pip and then update it to the latest version.

auxlib is required in python 3.6.1. Install it using `pip3 install auxlib`

Now install conda 4.2.7 using `pip3 install conda==4.2.7` and then update it using `conda update conda`.

Comment: I am using this way to install conda because I was having the same problem. But after execute `conda update conda` I obtain: `‘conda’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. I would like to restart the installation process, but now I can not find my conda installation. If I uninstall python, will I uninstall both, conda and python?